# how to implement macros in Go?

Tags: go, macros

I've project done in C++ where I used `#define` macros to give a name of the project, which I used in several places, I don't change this name often but sometimes I may need to change this, then I change this macro and rebuild my code. Now I'm converting this code to Go. Can someone suggest me how to implement this in Go? I'm not interested in using global variables for this purpose because I've many such macros and I doubt this cause my project to occupy more cpu and effect the performance.

Comment: Go does not have native C-style macros.

Comment: If you use constants there isn't really a performance difference compared to macros. The compiler can do the same sort of optimizations.

Answer (score 33):

Luckily, Go does not support macros.

There are two venues in Go to implement what is done using macros
in other programming languages:

- "Meta-programming" is done using [code generation](https://blog.golang.org/generate).
- "Magic variables/constants" are implemented using "symbol substitutions"
  at link time.

It appears, the latter is what you're after.

Unfortunately, the help on this feature is nearly undiscoverable
on itself, but it explained in the output of

```
$ go tool link -help
```

To cite the relevant bit from it:

> `-X definition`
>
> add string value `definition` of the form `importpath.name=value`

So you roll like this:

1. In any package, where it is convenient,
   you define a string constant the value of which you'd like to change at build time.

   Let's say, you define constant `Bar` in package `foo`.
2. You pass a special flag to the `go build` or `go install` invocation for the linking phase at compile time:

   ```
    $ go install -ldflags='-X foo.Bar="my super cool string"'
   ```

As the result, the produced binary will have the constant `foo.Bar`
set to the value "my super cool string" in its "read-only data" segment,
and that value will be used by the program's code.

See also the `go help build` output about the `-ldflags` option.

Comment: Can you explain why "luckily" Go does not support macros :/

Comment: @JenilMewada, simply because once you have macros you no longer see the real code of your program—you see something else from what the compiler will actually be compiling. Note that when I say "macros" I imply what people tend to colloquially understand by that name—that C's `#ifdef`-fery; "real" macros—in certain programming languages such as LISP—is a more interesting/complicated topic. Everyone who dealt with C, for sure more than once had to run the compiler in its special mode "dump what you get after expanding all the macros" to try to understand what the heck is going on.

Comment: @JenilMewada, note that Go does provide an easy to use and—which is more important—to understand, facility for "conditional compilation": [build constraints](https://golang.org/pkg/go/build/#hdr-Build_Constraints).

Comment: For a simple and common usage of macro, like check odd number, it will lead you to chose between something like `func odd(n int) bool{return n & 1 == 1}` with call stack and copy value costs or ugly code version: `if n & 1 == 1{...} && ... || ...`

Comment: @ϻαϻɾΣɀО-MaMrEzO, the function you mentioned in the "something like …" bit will be [happily inlined](https://play.golang.org/p/GJj9RLCbRpZ).

Comment: "It's a feature not a bug" is a really weak take.  Macros exist in many, many languages and in languages like C, or erlang, etc... go far beyond `#ifdef`ing code blocks out or constants.  Parametrized macros are an excellent tool to reduce code duplication and make things look cleaner and should be part of any normal preprocessor in a compiler.  I realize this question is dated, and I pray things have changed since then, but cursory google search tells me no.

Comment: @mritalian, in a comment I've mentioned LISP as an example of a PL with "real" macros, so yes, I'm aware they do exist. The problem is that most of the time when people ask about macros they do not mean _those_ things; rather, they mean macros which exist only until a run of preprocessing is done, and the compiler has no idea that they existed. I have reasonable exposure to C (and classic C++), and I, for one, would hate to see a feature like that in Go. Basically, that's what I have tried to postulate in my answer ;-)

Comment: @kostix "once you have macros you no longer see the real code of your program." Couldn't you say the same thing about the garbage collector?

Comment: @tedtanner, no, I couldn't. But don't we digress? I think such a discussion could be okay for a mailing list or r/programming, but this is the comment section under a post on SO.

Answer (score 13):

Go doesn't support `Macros`.
but you can use a constants inside a package and refer it where ever you need.

```
package constant
// constants.go file

const (
    ProjectName = "My Project"
    Title       = "Awesome Title"
)
```

and in your program

```
package main
import "<path to project>/constant" // replace the path to project with your path from GOPATH

func main() {
     fmt.Println(constant.ProjectName)
}
```

The project structure would be

```
project
   |- constant
   |      |- constants.go
   |-main.go
```

Comment: he also wishes to change the value when needed so using const would create problems.

Comment: He wants to change them at compile-time, not run-time. Just like macros in C/C++. `var` just adds unnecessary overhead.