# generate build timestamp in Go

Tags: go

I want in a Go program (using Go 1.11.1 on Debian/Linux/x86-64) to keep the build timestamp with a line explaining the last `git commit`.

In a C program (FWIW my [bismon](http://github.com/bstarynk/bismon/) project is doing something very similar), I would just generate some `_timestamp.c` file, e.g. with a `Makefile` recipe like:

```
_timestamp.c: 
    date +'const char my_timestamp[]='%c';%n' > $@
    (echo -n 'const char my_lastgitcommit[]="'; \
     git log --format=oneline --abbrev=12 --abbrev-commit -q | head -1 \
       | tr -d '\n\r\f\"\\\\' ; echo '";') >> $@
```

and I would link my program `myprog` with something like:

```
myprog: $(MYOBJECTS) _timestamp.c
    $(LINK.c) $(MYOBJECTS) _timestamp.c -o $@
    $(RM) _timestamp.c
```

Notice that `_timestamp.c` is automatically removed at each successful link. Of course in some header I would declare `extern const char my_timestamp[];` and `extern const char my_lastgitcommit[]:` and I would use e.g. `my_timestamp` and `my_lastgitcommit` in my `main.c` (and have `MYOBJECTS` contain `main.o`)

It looks like [`go generate`](https://golang.org/cmd/go/) could be used to behave in a similar way. I would like to have a package `"timestamp"` defining two string globals `timestamp.My_timestamp` and `timestamp.My_gitcommit`  but I don't exactly understand how to do it.

I tried to add some `timestamp/timestamp.go` file with

```
package timestamp

//go:generate date +'var My_timestamp = "%c"%n'

// Code generated - DO NOT EDIT.
```

But it did not change with `go generate` then `go install`

Of course, these timestamps should be constant strings at compile time, and I expect to find them when running the [strings(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strings.1.html) utility on the ELF executable.

BTW, I recall one of the motivations of [the `go` command](https://golang.org/doc/articles/go_command.html):

> An explicit goal for Go from the beginning was to be able to build Go code using only the information found in the source itself, not needing to write a makefile or one of the many modern replacements for makefiles. If Go needed a configuration file to explain how to build your program, then Go would have failed.

So I am still expecting something to go into the source code alone, without extra configuration for building.

In other words, I want to *generate* at every build a Go file similar to:

```
// generated timestamp.go file
package timestamp
var Buildtime = "Tue 30 Oct 2018 09:39:01 AM MET";
var Buildlastgitcommit = "7fde394b60bc adding timestamp.go"
```

The `Buildtime` string is generated by `date +%c`. The `Buildlastgitcommit` string might be generated by commands similar to what my `_timestamp.c` make rule is doing.

I need these strings to be constant and built-in the ELF executable produced by a Go build (which I would prefer to be done by *usual* commands, either without extra arguments to `go build` or any other build automation tool, or with some way to fail the build if the mandatory arguments are forgotten; hence [atanayel's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53045029/841108) is not enough). So I want the [strings(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strings.1.html) utility to find these strings quickly in the executable. And the generation of such files should be configured in some kind of files, not requiring extra arguments to builders.

I could consider switching to some other, *Go-friendly*, [build automation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Build_automation) system (but it seems that even with [gb](https://getgb.io/) I can't easily do what I want: quickly generate some simple `.go` file at every build). But I don't understand why it is so difficult to use *generated* Go files in Go programs. Generating simple code is following the [Unix philosophy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_philosophy), and has been practiced since many decades (e.g. see [goyacc](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/tools/cmd/goyacc) inspired by the old [yacc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yacc) program).

NB: the [rationale for `go generate`](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1V03LUfjSADDooDMhe-_K59EgpTEm3V8uvQRuNMAEnjg/edit) explicitly mentions that:

> It is not a goal of this proposal to build a generalized build system like the Unix `make(1)` utility.

and later

> once things are settled, the author commits the generated files to the source repository,

(and this is *not* my use case)

PS. I only care about POSIX systems; I really don't care if my Go software cannot be built on Windows. And I tend to think that (contrarily to what [`go` command motivation](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1V03LUfjSADDooDMhe-_K59EgpTEm3V8uvQRuNMAEnjg/edit) explains), in my particular case, I *do* need some build automation tool. In my [bastawigo](https://gitlab.com/bstarynk/bastawigo) toy project (GPLv3+), I am using `make` (driving the `go` command)

Comment: Do you need to use `go generate`? An alternative would declare these variables at the top-level in some package, and supply the values with which to populate them by setting the `-X` linker option: https://blog.alexellis.io/inject-build-time-vars-golang/

Comment: `go generate` doesn't modify the file that contains the command(s), it simply executes them with /bin/sh; much like `make`. Redirect the `date` output to a new file. Alternatively, assign to an existing variable at build time: https://blog.cloudflare.com/setting-go-variables-at-compile-time/

Comment: @Peter `go generate` executes the command directly, it does not use /bin/sh.

Comment: `go generate` is not called "automatically" by `go build` nor `go install`, so you can't fully automate what you want without needing to pass flags to go build, or having to run `go generate` manually prior to `go build`. Now if you're fine having to run `go generate` before a build, then a simple command could create / replace a `.go` source file having these values in a constant declaration.

Comment: I could consider using some other, Go-friendly, build automation system. But then, which one, and how to use it? According to [go command motivations](https://golang.org/doc/articles/go_command.html) I should be able to add something in the files for that purpose

Comment: The link you provided does not imply you should be able to add something to source files, only that already existing go files should be built without extra configuration. Injecting something like timestamp and git commit hash requires extra params or commands to run.

Comment: No extra parameters are needed, only the ability of running some commands at each build.

Comment: Yes, I understand that, but it's not possible with a single `go build` or `go install` command. You do need to run manually the command before that. At least with the current version. And I suspect it won't change in the future.

Answer (score 8):

As other answers mentioned, you can inject the needed values into the binary at build time.

For example if we have these package variables:

```
// build flags
var (
    BuildTime  string
    CommitHash string
    GoVersion  string
    GitTag     string
)
```

Then we can fill them using this bash script:

```
#!/bin/sh

clear

TRG_PKG='main'
BUILD_TIME=$(date +"%Y%m%d.%H%M%S")
CommitHash=N/A
GoVersion=N/A
GitTag=N/A

if [[ $(go version) =~ [0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+ ]];
then
    GoVersion=${BASH_REMATCH[0]}
fi

GV=$(git tag || echo 'N/A')
if [[ $GV =~ [^[:space:]]+ ]];
then
    GitTag=${BASH_REMATCH[0]}
fi

GH=$(git log -1 --pretty=format:%h || echo 'N/A')
if [[ GH =~ 'fatal' ]];
then
    CommitHash=N/A
else
    CommitHash=$GH
fi

FLAG="-X $TRG_PKG.BuildTime=$BUILD_TIME"
FLAG="$FLAG -X $TRG_PKG.CommitHash=$CommitHash"
FLAG="$FLAG -X $TRG_PKG.GoVersion=$GoVersion"
FLAG="$FLAG -X $TRG_PKG.GitTag=$GitTag"

if [[ $1 =~ '-i' ]];
then
    echo 'go install'
    go install -v -ldflags "$FLAG"
else
    echo 'go build'
    go build -v -ldflags "$FLAG"
fi
```

Sample code took from this [repo](https://github.com/dc0d/cliche).

Comment: Do you have any suggestions on reference material on injecting values into the binary at build time... I'm curious how that's done.

Comment: @SeanPianka Not anything other than the documentation for `go` command (https://golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-Compile_packages_and_dependencies) and bunch of blogs. Personally I wrote that package to just solve this and the rest of it is not much of use.

Comment: @KavehShahbazian sh doesn't understand the bash syntax used here. Can't edit because stack overflow requires at least 6 characters to change.

Answer (score 7):

You can use build time flags to do this. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49530118/4982148) explains it for a different use case, but yours is identical to it.
You should do something like this.

- Define a constant in your code something like `buildTime`
- When building for release , do something like `go build -ldflags='-X buildTime="My build time output from a command"'`
- Now your variable `buildTime` is constant and equals to `My build time output from a command`.
- You can use your previous command to find the correct `My build time output froma a command`.

Refer to the answer I linked for better explanation.

Comment: It is not only for release builds that I want the timestamp, but for *every* build. So your answer implies that Go's claim "to be able to build Go code using only the information found in the source itself" is false...

Comment: Release build was just an example. You can write a makefile and use this command for every build. Yes the claim is wrong that’s why they dont encourage this usage but the go generate model