# Golang remove duplicate code when handling error return

Tags: go, error-handling, code-duplication

I'm learning Golang by creating web-application. When working with Go I encountered this situation a lot

```
err = SomeFunction()

// Handling err
if err != nil {
   Logging(err)
   return err
}
```

In C or C++, the part "handling err" I can use MARCO or INLINE FUNCTION to remove duplicate code. Anyone knows how to do it in Golang ?

Comment: This pattern is idiomatic in Go, I recommend you to follow this pattern, each language has its own paradigms, you should respect them and follow.

Comment: Maybe improved in the future(Go2).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49527584/how-to-implement-macros-in-go

Comment: Two points: 1) you almost never should return naked `err` back, but instead augment the error with more context/details, eg `return fmt.Errorf("could not connect to database: %w", err)` 2. you either return error, or log it, not both. Since you should log it at the top-most caller anyway (your `main` or http handler or what you have)

Comment: @zerkms my idea is when an error occur it will print error from top-most caller to its last child (like backtrace). Is this any better way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

you can use
https://gitlab.com/opennota/macro

define macros like so
in input.go.tmpl

```
func MACRO_m1(a, b int) {
    a = b ^ 1
}

func main(){
   m1(v1, v2)
}
```

on commandline

```
macro input.go.tmpl output.go
```

will convert to

```
func main(){
     v1 = v2 ^ 1       
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The way inline function works in `Go` is different than how it works in C or other languages. `Go` compiler is intelligent enough to convert the much simpler functions to inline function in its compiled code.

So if you are looking to reduce duplication of code or reduce cognitive complexity of your code if your logger is doing certain write operations on files which would consume time, you can take below approach to create a anonymous function and assign it to variable and log your error.

```
func returnFromErr(){

    // Create a anonynous function and assign it a variable
    logErr := func (err error)bool {
        if err != nil{
            logger(err)
        }
        return err != nil
    }

    err := someFunction()
    // call the function and log your error. You can avoid certain level of duplication
    if logErr(err){return}

    fmt.Println("no error")
}

func main(){
returnFromErr()

}
```