# How to define a local label in macro definition of go assembly for avoiding the problem of label multiple defined?

Tags: go, assembly, macros, label

I don't know how to use LOCAL to define a local label in macro definition with go assembly. But it is very important for me to achieve it, as I need speed up the program using macro definition(including macro function).

I search a lot of references, but no solution is found. I expect an instruction to define the local label in macro definition with go assembly.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49527584/how-to-implement-macros-in-go [cgo to do it](https://deathbykeystroke.com/articles/20220106-real-macros-in-go.html)

Comment: @Para: Those links appear to be about macros in Go, not in assembly using the Go toolchain's dialect of assembly language.  If those are applicable to GoAsm, you should probably comment that macros work the same in .asm files, if that's true.

Comment: As far as I know Go's assembler simply doesn't support this.

Comment: The Go assembler does not have a mechanism to define macro-local labels; the `LOCAL` macro is for a different purpose.  You might be able to use the token-pasting operator to build unique label names.